# Blob as source docx/pptx/xlsm/etc as iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having a problem identical to this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721709/view-blob-excel-file-into-iframe) (unanswered) question. Is it possible to create an iframe of docx/pptx/xlsm/etc with a blob? For reference, here's some code

AngularJS snippet to have docx iframes

```js
    get_file_data().then(function(response){ //assume get_file_data works
        memtype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: memtype});
        var blob_url = $window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
        var office_url = "http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=";
        var url = office_url + blob_url;
        $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
```

And then in my html file:

```html
<iframe ng-src = "{{content}}"> </frame>
```

It doesn't work likely because `blob_url` has blob:// as a prefix, how can I fix this to make it work? Or is this something that can't be done? For some reason, this approach works for pdf files

Comment: Hi nodel, did u find any solution for this problem?

Comment: no, it seems like the chrome browser only provides native pdf support